# What did Estarossa do to the revenge counter of Meliodas in the Episode 20 Season 2 of Nanatsu no Taizai?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

From the competition held by Gloxinia and Drole where the death of Meliodas happened the part where Meliodas is about to unleash the revenge counter to kill all the commandments, Gowther said that the power accumulated of Meliodas from that Revenge Counter is 30x stronger from the last time he used it, but it suddenly disappear when Estarossa touches Meliodas dagger.

What happened? How did that strong magic disappear instantly?

Comment: This might not be the right answer but Estarossa is commandment of love and revenge comes from hatred. So he might be able to cancel it. At least that's what I think. Since I am not sure that's why I am commenting instead of posting answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about Estarossa's commandment. I read some site about it that his commandment can suppress Meliodas's Revenge Counter.

**Estarossa's COMMANDMENT**

> "Those who stand against him with hatred in their hearts will be
>   rendered powerless, and will lose the ability or capacity to inflict
>   harm or damage to any persons in his presence." This allows Estarossa
>   to negate any type of power or attack that bears animosity, and was
>   potent enough to completely nullify Meliodas' Revenge Counter

link:https://comicvine.gamespot.com/estarossa/4005-133352/